# Xcode 4.3.1 import files to new project

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

I accidentaly remove target in my previews project and i decided to create new one and import files. I added all frameworks and copy my AppDelegate files. When i build project i have this error.

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AppDelegate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Please help..

Answer (score 5):

Check in your target's build phases that the `AppDelegate.m` is in the *Compile Sources* and the `AppDelegate.h` is in the *Copy Headers Section*

Answer (score 3):

Make sure all .m files (specifically AppDelegate) are included in the target membership. (check box under file inspector when class is selected)

Comment: I created new project transfer my files and its done. Thank you for reply.